# Component getting rendered again when app coming from background, React Native iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

When my app goes to background and it is opened again, there is a new instance triggered. So if we successively open it again and again, the number of times it is rendered also increases successively.

Comment: Hard to diagnose without some code.  The only time I've seen something similar to that is when we had some listeners registered in the `componentWillMount` so that they were re-registered each time the component was created.  Are you doing anything like that with AppState?  Sometimes people will watch the app state to look for push notifications or to download data when the app starts up

Comment: Hi @GarrettMcCullough

Thanks for the inputs. Actually the problem was with the navigation library I was using.